# CSS: width property is not working for div tags

Tags: html, css, width

I am trying to create a Product catalog. I have planned to create multiple rows whereas in each row there would be 2 products each.

Thus in each row the 1st product belongs to product-1 class and 2nd product belongs to product - 2 class.

I have divided the page vertically into two parts using `float:left` and specified `width:50%` for both classes.

And also for product-2 class I have specified `left:50%` (to push it to left)

I have kept `display:block` , `position:relative` for both classes.

But the `width` property seems to not be working.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/abhaygc/0pfygcbe/

Code Snippet:

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
.header{

  background-color: white;
  height:8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: "Roboto";
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
}
#clear{
  clear: both;
 }
.logo{
 margin-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
#logo:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.links{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
a{
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 /*top: 25px;*/

 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;

 color:black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 background-color:#cccccc; 
}

.content{
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 height: 92%;
 margin-top: 0px;

}

#clear{
 clear: both;
}

.image{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-style: dashed;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.product-1{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
 
 
 margin-top: 5%;
 
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 width: 40%;
 overflow: hidden;

 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.product-2{
 display: block;
 position: relative;


 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;

 
 margin-top: 5%;

 float: left;

 left: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;

 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="products.css">
 <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img id="logo"src="logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">   
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="products.html">Products</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="register.html">Register</a>
   <a href="home.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="home.html">About</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-4.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 2"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="clear"></div>

  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-6.jpg" alt="Image 3"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 4"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Check my answer below. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` in `.product-2` does does not *visibly* work because of the `left: 50%` property you have assigned to it. If you remove that, then assigning a `width` to `.product-2` will work.
 I have added a `<div class="row">` to each of your division to distinctly divide them as a row. I assigned `float-right` to `.product-2` and a sample `width` of `200px` so you can see the `width` working. Hope this answers your question, good luck

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
.header{

  background-color: white;
  height:8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: "Roboto";
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
}
#clear{
  clear: both;
 }
.logo{
 margin-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
#logo:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.links{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
a{
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 /*top: 25px;*/

 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;

 color:black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 background-color:#cccccc; 
}

.content{
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 height: 92%;
 margin-top: 0px;

}

#clear{
 clear: both;
}

.image{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-style: dashed;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.product-1{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
 
 margin-top: 5%;
 
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 width: 175px; /* sample width */
 overflow: hidden;

 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.product-2{
 display: block;
 position: relative;

 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;

 margin-top: 5%;
 float: right;
 width: 175px; /* sample width */
 overflow: hidden;

 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img id="logo"src="logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">   
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="products.html">Products</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="register.html">Register</a>
   <a href="home.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="home.html">About</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-4.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 2"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>
                </div>

  <div id="clear"></div>

                <div class="row">
  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-6.jpg" alt="Image 3"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 4"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>
                </div>

 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, it does work with the width but you are push the element using the `left` so you cannot see the rest of the `<div>` element when you assign a big width. Example: try using `left:50%` and `width: 3000px` at the same time. Then zoom out your browser. You can see that the `<div>` will be `3000px` long :)

Comment: does that means `left:50%` is pushing right side div at length 50% of display size from the end of left side div? Because I thought `left` assigns distance from left side of display but it seems to assign distance from element's position.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
.header{

  background-color: white;
  height:8%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-style: "Roboto";
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
}
#clear{
  clear: both;
 }
.logo{
 margin-top: 12px;
 float: left;
 left: 0px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}
#logo:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.links{
 display: block;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
a{
 position: relative;
 right: 0px;
 /*top: 25px;*/

 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;

 color:black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 background-color:#cccccc; 
}

.content{
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 height: 92%;
 margin-top: 0px;

}

#clear{
 clear: both;
}

.image{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-style: dashed;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-1{
 display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-left: 10%; */
    /* padding-right: 10%; */
    margin-top: 5%;
    float: left;
    /* left: 0px; */
    width: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0 5%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width:1px;
}

.product-2{
 display: block;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-left: 10%; */
    /* padding-right: 10%; */
    /* margin-top: 15px; */
    float: left;
    /* left: 50%; */
    width: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0 5%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="products.css">
 <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img id="logo"src="logo.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">   
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="products.html">Products</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="register.html">Register</a>
   <a href="home.html">Contact</a>
   <a href="home.html">About</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-4.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 2"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="clear"></div>

  <div class="product-1 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-6.jpg" alt="Image 3"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-2 product">
   <div class="image">
     <img src="slide-5.jpg" alt="Image 4"/>
   </div>
   <div class="caption">
    
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products.js"></script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/0pfygcbe/23/

This works fine. Let me know if there is any problem.
Thanks

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but couldn't accept it because before you @emineminems gave the solution.

Comment: @user8810517, emineminems answer is wrong since it is not working in mobiles and he applied a fixed width for both product1 and product2.

Comment: @user8810517, when you position your most right div with left:50%; value, that div maintains a block space from it's left hand.So No other element can't reach in to that space.

Comment: does that means left:50% is pushing right side div at length 50% of display size from the end of left side div?

Comment: @VSM Read the title. He asked why the width was not working, I answered him. Why are you saying my answer is wrong? The `width` in `px` is just a sample ...

Comment: @emineminems, my friend, read the content carefully, not the title.He mentioned that width is 50%. Your sample should be relevant to the content provided above.

Comment: @VSM Sir, that is subjective. But, I do respect that opinion. Yet, that is no reason to declare my answer as 'wrong' for the given context

Comment: @user8810517, yep, That 50% is from the left margin of view port, not from the end of left side div.

Comment: @emineminems, Could you check whether your answer is work in every window size? If any one put an answer here it should works in any situation, not in the specific situation.

Comment: @VSM it is just a sample.. I could simply remove the demo yet my statement still **answers** his **question** regarding why the width is not "working". This question is not a matter of designing the page for him. It is to make him understand a concept